# Global Picklist Value Sets

Tags: picklist, global-picklist

I have a ObjA_custom_field__c on Object_A__c, ObjB_custom_field__c on Object_B__c.
Both these are picklist fields, that have the same value and serve same purpose.

Instead of remembering to add same values to the Custom picklists, I created a Global Picklist Value Set.

My problem is how can i restrict the existing picklist fields to get values from the Global Picklist Value Sets.

Note that, the custom picklist fields on both objects existed before creating the global picklist value set.

Comment: You try using "Promote to Global Value Set" on an existing picklist fields. (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_global_value_sets.htm)

Comment: As per your reference link, this allows promoting values on an existing picklist to Global Picklist vlaue Set.  But what i am after is other way round.  I have a Global Picklist Value Set, and I have a Custom Picklist field with values that are exactly the same as those in the Global Picklist Value Set. I want this piclist field to get values from the global picklist value set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not possible as per the link
[here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJegAAE)

While you can promote the values of an existing Picklist to create a new Global Value Set, you cannot draw values for an existing picklist from an existing Global Value  Set.

Comment: Yes, you can move values to new 'Global Value Set' but you cannot draw values.